# OSX: DLL Has A Reference to Itself?

Tags: macos

I have a library built on OSX 10.6.  It runs fine with apps on that version of MacOS.  On OSX 10.7 it doesn't run right because it can't find all its dependencies properly, and I suspect it has something to with it thinking that it is linked to itself.  Why would screens.so show when I run "otool -L" on screens.so?  Is it something that I should remove, and if so, how?

```
screens.so:
    screens.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 111.1.4)
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.3)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 275.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 136.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 12.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickTime.framework/Versions/A/QuickTime (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1327.73.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libwx_macud-2.8.0.dylib (compatibility version 2.6.0, current version 2.8.4)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.4.0)
    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 34.0.0)
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/33455590

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is just fine - the first line is merely the ID string of the dynamic library, it shows you what will be used at link time to embed into the executable. For example:

```
$ otool -L /usr/lib/libz.dylib      
/usr/lib/libz.dylib:
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.0.0)
```

this shows you that linking `-lz` will result in `/usr/lib/libz.1.dylib` load command in the binary.

But back to your problem -- it has nothing to do with the first line, it has to do with this line:

```
    /usr/lib/libwx_macud-2.8.0.dylib (compatibility version 2.6.0, current version 2.8.4)
```

which is linking a library that doesn't exist in Lion - are you sure you need it?

Comment: Thank you, I do to ship a wx library.  Good to know that seeing the first line is OK.